# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

Since the Oct 1st Facebook update requiring SSL for canvas apps my Facebook Application has stopped working and displays the error:

The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I'm using the C# Facebook SDK, and my app is ASP.NET MVC3

I've bought an SSL certificate and it seemed to install OK - but still getting this error.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmmm, check the date and time setting on your server! I found mine to be set to 2002 for some stupid reason! Once it was set to the correct date, the certificate was valid and all is good.

Hope this helps someone else out!

Answer (score 0):

I had my local security policy on the server configured incorrectly. Go to Local Security Policy > Public Key Policis > Certificate Path Validation Setting. On the Network Retrieval tab make sure "Define the policy settings" is not checked and "Allow issuer certificate (AIA) retrieval during path validation (recommended) is also not checked.