# Facebook Connect: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: asp.net, facebook, certificate

Since today, without changing anything on my own server, I'm getting this error when trying to connect with Facebook via Facebook Connect.

I noticed this post: [The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856475/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure)
But the solutions offered there don't work and on top of that my code has always worked.
Locally it still works fine, but as soon as I connect on production it fails.

**UPDATE**
I now found that I can still use Facebook Connect on my other sites on the same VPS...only this site suddenly has issues. It's shared code, so it's definitely not something in my code. What could it be?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.]
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception) +2755228
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +470
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +86
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +262
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +470
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +86
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +262
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +470
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +86
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +262
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +470
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +8551966
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) +230
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) +645
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) +9
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +87
   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) +1467
   System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +84
   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async) +816

[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8420768
   oAuthFacebook.WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest) +441



Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212
```

Comment: As I understand your application can't validate some remote certificate. You can start diagnostics by connecting to the server which presents supposedly invalid certificate with your browser or openssl and seeing what they say about the remote certificate. It can happen that the certificate is indeed invalid.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that exactly? "connecting to the server which presents supposedly invalid certificate with your browser or openssl and seeing what they say about the remote certificate."

Comment: Point your browser to that address.

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding, but which address? I believe my browser is already pointing to the address as I'm receiving the error on there...how can I debug? (replaced my actual site with example.com): http://www.example.com/login.aspx?loggedin=true&code=AQD1U6RSkX4JbaH5N1zABh3i5Y10tFiwoH_K8dl6t3CrW8O5TCMz4RsIkfBwdBGrhWo0e0CIWCMvNTB8D2TydfMKW5-txiFZzRWsQ7O6C1xiyLRzHZXByg4PI8JMBYmFVUrJ0BSFjxWu7IUNYShGtljTgzac6hMP0t7tKq85tYnY_vhsyrRjoqZNRNm_CU2lHU_5AVOOngDsVBLTEAJjcygmnYTUONUV35FJ5VoxylJMfdWxIVM8VzanHtkI9HtB0ua09xxb1DEBzwLspjuC9Ym08vmo71vwG0qE1WOpwecdNLwKDzUTg-pBW4mcvOQ9kR2Gx8SSPCu8#_=_

Comment: The exception happens on the server, in the code which connects to some third-party resource. You need to find out the exact address that your code connects to, and test this address locally on your computer.

Comment: Wow, reboot of my IIS Application pool fixed the issue. :) Tnx!

Comment: There were recently issue affecting certificates on some Facebook servers, which may have been related (https://developers.intern.facebook.com/bugs/666744746763489/)